# Creating sqs client object with aiobotocore returns a couroutine instead of the actual object

Tags: pytest, amazon-sqs, python-3.8, aiobotocore

I am running python 3.8  and aiobotocore 2.5

I try creating an sqs client with the code below

```
    async def _create_sqs_client(self):
    '''
    Creates an SQS client using our botocore session.
    '''

    sqs_client = await(self._botocore_session.create_client(
        'sqs', **self._connection_details
    ))

    return sqs_client
```

calling the function  `async with self._create_sqs_client() as client` returns a coroutine object  `coroutine object square at 0x00000185C31E7D80> _client:"none`